# Spring boot Security - ldap Authentication with Database roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

Im working on a project with spring boot and spring security, I want to authenticate the user against Active Directory over LDAP Protocol and retrieving authorization of this user from User Table (DB).

how can i tell spring security to get aithorization from db instead of authorities from AD and how can i ensure that a given user in AD has his own record in DB?

My SecurityConfiguration Class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        CorsFilter corsFilter) {

        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;             this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**");        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .usernameParameter("usr")
            .passwordParameter("pwd")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
```

My UserDetailsService is :

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomainUserDetailsService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
        return userFromDatabase.map(user -> {
            if (!user.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin,
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the " +
        "database"));
    }
}
```

SecurityUtils:

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        String userName = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
            } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
                userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            }
        }
        return userName;
    }
```

I'm really confused and I don't know how to make things works
Thank you so much for the help

Comment: would you be able to solve your problem? I am running into same issue. Could you pls share what have worked for?

Comment: Hey, the issue was solved, could you please tell me what is your issue with not running the authentication LDAP with spring security, boot ...

Comment: Hi @mesmed, how did you get it to work? My code is quite similar to what you describe in this question (a bit simper, though). In my securityConfig I have a configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method that sets my custom UserDetailsService implementation in the auth. My UserDetailsService has a loadUserByUsername method that retrieves the User object (and corresponding authorities) from the DB. However when I run SecurityContextHolder.getContext(),getAuthentication().getPrincipal I still get an LdapUserDetailsImpl object instead of a User.